# How do I block "hung out" auto-posts?

Tags: google-plus

If I click on my Profile in Google Plus, a number of entries are of the form "Dave Babbitt hung out. 4 people hung out." and are blocking my view of the rest of the entries. Is there a way I can keep Google from posting these on my wall?

Comment: FYI, only you and those people can see the posts if the hangouts were private.